# How to split osm data

Tags: openstreetmap, algorithm, splitting, osmosis

I have a gigantic OSM geodata file of a city, and I want to split it into smaller files according to each group of  tags.

I googled it up and i found that there is a jar file caller splitter.jar . i downloaded it and made a test with a small osm geodata, but what i got is a .pbf file which is not readable.

is there any recommended software to split the osm data or i have to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "swiss-knife" for OpenStreetMap data is [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis). It's a command-line Java application for linux and windows. [Learn-OSM provides a great introduction](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osmosis/) for new users. With osmosis you can split OSM files by a bbox, a polygon or by specific tags. Check out the [latest detailed usage wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.44) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis).

Example with pbf file (much much smaller - it's binary rather than text!):

```
osmosis --read-pbf city.pbf\
        --tf accept-ways cycleway=track,lane\
        --used-node --write-xml citycycling.osm
```

or with an osm XML file:

```
osmosis --read-xml city.osm\
        --tf accept-ways highway=*\
        --used-node --write-xml highways.osm
```

Comment: 3 mins to slow ... :)

Comment: You provide some better resources though :)